# Resizing UILabel in UITableViewCell not updating before render

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uikit

I have a reusable UITableViewCell as part of my storyboard, where I need to sizeToFit after the text has been set. To achieve this I am performing the sizeToFit in the layoutSubviews method of my cell class.

But the problem is that I'm not seeing any updates, I've tried setting needsDisplay/Layout but I can't see any updates until the cell needs to be completely re-rendered (either when I scroll down and up or when I begin & end updates to the tableView).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this by creating a class for the UILabel and then performing the needs inside layoutSubviews for my subclassed UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autolayout then try setting [preferredMaxLayoutWidth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW28) property of label in your cell's `layoutSubviews` method. You need to call `[super layoutSubviews]` again after setting that property.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // Make sure that label's text is set by now
    self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.label.frame.size.width;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```